# Error when wrapping text in a div

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

Can you tell me why there's a break after `varun09` in the picture below? It's kind of weird because it only happens whenever the statement is bigger than the actual width of the `<div>`, and I'd like to know how to wrap the text? I want the vertical scroll option, but not the horizontal scrolling bar.

I am populating the `<div>` with Mysql data through Php.

The code is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['user_name'].' '.$row['chat_body'].'</p><br> ';
}
```

[image: why a line break ?]

Comment: You don't need a `br` when wrapping it inside `<p>` tag.. Also add a class to `<p class="user_comments"` and set the style for that property.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` will do the job

Comment: it's wrapping now but why is it still breaking the line ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the white-space in order for it to wrap for you, but the space after varun09 will cause the next one to go to the next line. Try this combination:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XqStw/)

```
p { word-wrap: break-word; white-space:pre; }​
```

[Info on **white-space** here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Thanx  but any idea on  why  it's still breaking the line  after varun09 ?

Comment: white-space:pre(which fixes the line break) and white-space:normal (which wraps the text) are working  but i can't use  them  together, and word-wrap: break-word;  is not working ....

Comment: Unfortunately it'll only work on newer browsers, which one are you using?

Comment: yes you are right it's  working on chrome  not  working on mozilla and ie 
any suggestion on making it work on old browsers too ?

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ahiyeg/1/edit)**

use for your element the CSS property `word-wrap`:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use word-wrap property:

```
selector {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```